# Constants Naming Convention

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-5.0

Is this a correct naming convention?. **MAT** is the abbreviation of the tool we are building.

```
public static class Constants
{
   public const string MATApplicationId = "xxx";
}
```

Comment: The usual .NET naming convention is `CamelEvenForAcronyms` (e.g. `System.Xml.XmlDocument`), so `MataApplicationId` in this case. A historical exception to this rule is `System.Math.PI`.

Comment: Check yourself on [Framework Design Guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)